# Thought Process for largest Container of Water Problem

Tags: algorithms, dynamic-programming, arrays

There is a common leetcode problem that asks

> Given $n$ non-negative integers $a_1, a_2, \dots, a_n$, where each represents a point at coordinate $(i, a_i)$. Then $n$ vertical lines are drawn such that the two endpoints of the line $i$ are at $(i, a_i)$ and $(i, 0)$. Find two lines, which, together with the x-axis forms a container, such that the container contains the most water.

What I'm interested in is not the solution but the thought process for how you approached the problem and first started to break it down.

Example:

[image]

> Input: height = [1,8,6,2,5,4,8,3,7]

> Output: 49

> Explanation: The vertical above lines are represented by array [1,8,6,2,5,4,8,3,7]. In this case, the max area of water (blue section) the container can contain is 49.

https://leetcode.com/problems/container-with-most-water/